# Call MySQL Stored Procedure using SimpleJdbcCall in Java

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have not done Java in a long time, so I decided to create a small application to manage a project. I am making a call to the database to insert a new user. I have the stored procedure created. I called the stored procedure and add a new user successfully using MySQL Workbench. However, when I made a call from the application using SimpleJdbcCall, it did not insert the new user. It did not throw an exception either. To eliminate issue with connecting to the database, I was able to call a different stored procedure that returns the total count of existing email without issue. I have not been able to figure why. I would appreciate any guidance on the cause of this issue.

**Code that is not working: Update**

```
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class UserRepository implements IUser<User> {
    private SimpleJdbcCall sj;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;
    
    @Bean
    public SimpleJdbcCall setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
        sj = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate);
        return sj;
    }
    
    private boolean emailExists(String email) {
         SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                    .addValue("email", email); 
        Map<String, Object> out = 
                sj.withProcedureName(ApplicationConstant.APPLICATION_EMAIL_COUNT)
                .execute(in);
       Integer count =  (Integer) out.get("total_email");
       return count > 0;
    }
    
    @Override
    public User create(User user) {
        if(emailExists(user.getEmail().trim().toLowerCase())) throw new ApiException("Email already in use. Please login using your email.");
        try {
            String firstName = user.getFirstName();
            String lastName = user.getLastName();
            String email = user.getEmail();
            String password = user.getPassword();
             SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                        .addValue("firstName", firstName,Types.NVARCHAR)
                        .addValue("lastName", lastName,Types.NVARCHAR)
                        .addValue("email", email,Types.NVARCHAR)
                        .addValue("password", password,Types.NVARCHAR)
                        .addValue("user_id", 0, Types.BIGINT);
            Map<String, Object> out = 
                    sj.withProcedureName("UspUserUpsert")
                    .withCatalogName("manageproject")
                    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                    .declareParameters(
                      new SqlParameter("firstName", Types.NVARCHAR),
                      new SqlParameter("lastName", Types.NVARCHAR),
                      new SqlParameter("email", Types.NVARCHAR),
                      new SqlParameter("password", Types.NVARCHAR),
                      new SqlOutParameter("user_id", Types.BIGINT)  
                    )
                    .execute(in);
    
            Long userId = (Long) out.get("user_id");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new ApiException("An error occurs. Please try again.");
        }
        return user;
    }
    
}
```

**Parameter Values:**

```
MapSqlParameterSource {firstName=John, lastName=Doe, email=jdoe@gmail.com, password=123456.}
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
DELIMITER //;
CREATE PROCEDURE UspUserUpsert(
 IN firstName       VARCHAR(50),
 IN lastName        VARCHAR(50),
 IN email           VARCHAR(100),
 IN `password`      VARCHAR(255),
 OUT user_id        INT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
     
    SELECT 
        id 
    INTO user_id
    FROM 
        `user` 
    WHERE
        email = @email;
    
     START TRANSACTION;
     IF (user_id > 0) THEN
        UPDATE 
            `user` u
        SET
            u.address = 'TESTING'
        WHERE
            u.user_id = user_id;
     END IF;
     IF (ISNULL(user_id) =  1 OR user_id = 0) THEN
         INSERT INTO User (
            first_name,
            last_name,
            email,
            `password`
        )
        VALUES(
            firstName,
            lastName,
            email,
            `password`
        );
     SELECT 
        last_insert_id()
     INTO user_id;
     END IF;
    COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What value did you get for `userId`?

Comment: The userId is always null because it did not insert the record in the database. I am known to make stupid mistakes as well, so I copy the name of the stored procedure and each parameter so that I don't have any spelling error.

Comment: Have you checked so as to ensure your user object actually has the values you expect contained therein (i.e. user.getFirstName() etc..)?

Comment: Without seeing the SP it's difficult to say. I mean it might have a select in it that is simply not met and therefore no insert takes place

Comment: I updated it to include the stored procedure.

Comment: @mkane I looked at parameter's values, and they looked correct.

Comment: I would call it with your db client using the exact same parameters. One potential problem - the `@` in the email address is a special character

Comment: @g00se that's a good point, but I would expect it to throw an exception or some other error message. Is there an equivalent to MS SQL Tuning Template in MySQL? That tool allows me to see what the application sends to the server.  I can grab the exact query and execute it myself.

Comment: Well you can definitely turn on logging in the server

Comment: I think it may not like the way I initialize the SimpleJdbcCall. I commented out the code that is checking for existing email, and I was able to insert a new user and retrive the Id.

Comment: Maybe the email address contains whitespace?

Comment: @g00se I mofied the Bean and intialize and SimpleJdbcCall ever time I made a call to the database. It solved my problem. I am still going over the documentation trying to understand if that is the desired behavior.

Comment: Sorry I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by that

Comment: @g00se I meant to say instantiate not initialize. I posted the changes made as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes that I made to get the code to work.

```
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class UserRepository implements IUser<User> {
    private SimpleJdbcCall sj;
   // Declare JdbcTemplate as an instance variable.
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;
    
    // Change to a void
    @Bean
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
       // sj = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate);
       // return sj;
    }
    
    private boolean emailExists(String email) {
         SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                    .addValue("email", email); 
        // Instantiate sj here.
        sj = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate);
        Map<String, Object> out = 
                sj.withProcedureName(ApplicationConstant.APPLICATION_EMAIL_COUNT)
                .execute(in);
       Integer count =  (Integer) out.get("total_email");
       return count > 0;
    }
    
    @Override
    public User create(User user) {
        if(emailExists(user.getEmail().trim().toLowerCase())) throw new ApiException("Email already in use. Please login using your email.");
        try {
            String firstName = user.getFirstName();
            String lastName = user.getLastName();
            String email = user.getEmail();
            String password = user.getPassword();
             SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                        .addValue("firstName", firstName,Types.NVARCHAR)
                        .addValue("lastName", lastName,Types.NVARCHAR)
                        .addValue("email", email,Types.NVARCHAR)
                        .addValue("password", password,Types.NVARCHAR)
                        .addValue("user_id", 0, Types.BIGINT);
            // Instantiate sj here.
            sj = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate);
            Map<String, Object> out = 
                    sj.withProcedureName("UspUserUpsert")
                    .withCatalogName("manageproject")
                    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                    .declareParameters(
                      new SqlParameter("firstName", Types.NVARCHAR),
                      new SqlParameter("lastName", Types.NVARCHAR),
                      new SqlParameter("email", Types.NVARCHAR),
                      new SqlParameter("password", Types.NVARCHAR),
                      new SqlOutParameter("user_id", Types.BIGINT)  
                    )
                    .execute(in);
    
            Long userId = (Long) out.get("user_id");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new ApiException("An error occurs. Please try again.");
        }
        return user;
    }
    
}
```